# php/html form subject line missing

Tags: php, html, web-development-server

Having problem in sending form input to email, using php code.

```
<?php
$emailTo="testing_testing@gmail.com";
$subject = $POST_['username'];
$content = $_POST['course'] . $_POST['message'] . $_POST['tel'];
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];
mail($emailTo, $subject, $content, $headers);
?>
```

HTML Form Code:

```
<form  method="post">
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" required> </br>
        <input id="tel" type = "tel" name="tel" placeholder="Phone no." required></br>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email id" required></br>
        <input list="course" name="course">
        <datalist id="course">
               <option value="IELTS">
               <option value="English Speaking">
               <option value="Computers">
               <option value="Accounting">
               <option value="Fashion Designing">
               <option value="Hospitality and Tourism">
               <option value="General Enquiry">
        </datalist>

    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Any Message !"></textarea>

    <INPUT id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

This code does not set the subject field as it says - nosubject. Where as in the php code I am assigning the value of username as the subject field.

Comment: `$POST_` is a typo. Use error reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your declaration of the `$subject` variable:

```
$subject = $POST_['username'];
```

Should be

```
$subject = $_POST['username'];
```

Hope this helps :)